MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign_key constraint fails
I have this error:

MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign_key constraint fails

when executing this code:
INSERT INTO networks (owner_name, name, password, ip, visible)
VALUES ('alex', 'alex_net', '1234', '192.168.1.1', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE name='alex_net', password = '1234', ip = '192.168.1.1', visible = 1;

But when I execute it on PhPMyAdmin it works perfectly.
Why does it fail on the aplication but works on PhPMyAdmin?
I'm using MySqlConnector/Mono
C# function that executes query:
public static bool InsertOrUpdateNetwork(MySqlConnection connection, NetworkSO networkData)
{
    string sql =
        $"INSERT INTO networks (owner_name, name, password, ip, visible) " +
        $"VALUES ('{networkData.ownerName}', '{networkData.name}', '{networkData.password}', '{networkData.ip}', {networkData.visible}) " +
        $"ON DUPLICATE KEY " +
        $"UPDATE name='{networkData.name}', password='{networkData.password}', ip='{networkData.ip}', visible={networkData.visible}";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return result > 0;
}

SHOW CREATE networks & users:
CREATE TABLE networks (
 owner_name varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 password varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 ip varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 visible tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (owner_name),
 UNIQUE KEY owner_name_UNIQUE (owner_name),
 CONSTRAINT fk_network_owner_name FOREIGN KEY (owner_name) REFERENCES users (name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE users (
name varchar(16) NOT NULL, 
password varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, 
logged tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (name), 
UNIQUE KEY name_UNIQUE (name) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Complete console log:
MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (sql7721749.networks, CONSTRAINT fk_network_owner_name` FOREIGN KEY (owner_name) REFERENCES users (name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I managed to "solve" this issue by adding SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; before the main query string and adding SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; after the query string.
This allowed me to insert/update the data and when I deleted the user the network constrained by the user name also was deleted, so it still works as intended.
But I wonder why it happened and whether it's the right solution.

"Why does it fail on the aplication but works on PhPMyAdmin?" - Can you show how you're executing it from the application?  Perhaps there's some difference not shown here.  Maybe it's not the code itself but perhaps the configuration is pointing to a different instance of the database?

Provide SHOW CREATE TABLE networks;, also provide the same for all tables which are mentioned in FK rows. PS. Check that both C# app and PMA works with the same database.

In the last edit I show how I managed to "solve" this issue.

The error "MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign_key constraint fails" typically indicates that there is a problem with a foreign key constraint in your database schema. This means that the networks table has a foreign key that references another table, and the value you're trying to insert or update does not exist in the referenced table.
So i would suggest you look at the other table and check if the value exists.
Another reasons could be case sensitive issues or the connectivity of the database or database table.
For more info check this site:  https://sebhastian.com/mysql-error-1452/

This is not the problem since I can execute the query on phpMyAdmin.

phpMyAdmin has got another rights.
If your FOREIGN KEY is looking for a key (record) exists in another table (for example in table "B"), but your actual command is working in the table "A", I can imagine your user has no rights in table "B".
I created some faults like this in mssql, but I think the logic is the same at the foreign keys in mysql.
It is easy to check, I think it is worth a try.

And how do I check that?
I'm using the same user in phpMyAdmin and in the C# project.
